# initialize struct to zero except one field

Tags: c, struct

consider the following struct:

```
typedef struct _sampleStruct{
    bool b;
    int i;
    double d;
    int arr[10];
}sampleStruct;
```

I want to initialize a **global** instance of that struct such that `b` is initialized to `true` and rest of the fields are initialized to 0.
in addition, I want the initialization to take place where I declare it, i.e I **don't** want to do something like that:

```
sampleStruct globalStruct = {0};

int someFunc()
{
    //...
    globalStruct.b = true;
    //...
}
```

is there a way to do that?
I thought about doing something like that:

```
sampleStruct globalStruct = {.b = true, 0};
```

does it **promise** that all other fields are always zero?

Comment: Note: Names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation for all namespaces. Don't use them in application code!

Comment: @Olaf Symbols with a single leading underscore is only reserved in the global scope (so for any normal structure definition it's not allowed). Symbols with double (or more) underscores, or with underscore followed by an upper-case letter is reserved in all scopes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I should have differentiated, thanks for clarification. Anyway, `typedef`s are commonly at file-scope. So this very likely applies here. But yes, as OP does not provide a [mcve], it **could** be at block scope.

Comment: `typedef`s cease to exist after compilation and so can have an underscore. A typedef is not a symbol (a function or global variable is).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> does it promise that all other fields are always zero?

Yes. The members that are not explicitly initialized will be zero initialized as part of the designated initializer. You don't even need that `0` there. This:

```
sampleStruct globalStruct = {.b = true};
```

should suffice.

Comment: Not exactly. They are set to `0` (integers), `0.0` (floats) or _null pointer_. Except for integers, that does not necessarily mean zero-bits. And that is not related to designated initialisers. As `b` is the first field, an initialiser `{ true }` will work identically. A designated initialiser is just more clear.

Comment: Where are you reading those from? My answer only says *zero initialized*.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is guaranteed by C11 6.7.9/21:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

"Aggregate" is standard gibberish meaning: array or struct or union. As opposed to a plain, single value variable ("scalar").

In the above, "initialized as if it had static storage duration" means (6.7.9/10):

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>   — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a
>   null pointer;
>   — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to
>   (positive or unsigned) zero;
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is
>   initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is
>   initialized to zero bits;
>   — if it is a union, the first named member
>   is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding
>   is initialized to zero bits;

This applies to all forms of initializers in an initializer list. Designated initializers is no exception nor special case.